# Multiple AJAX calls - 1st to fetch data and turn into JSON object & 2nd to update $_SESSION info

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call which pulls data from the table and then transforms into a JSON object

Because I am also doing a lot with PHP as well I need to have a 2nd AJAX call
immediately after the first that will update $_SESSION info
I have tried putting

```
$_SESSION['company_id'] = $_POST['companyid'];
```

in the same file that handles the 1st AJAX call but it then doesn't process the data from the first call, hence I need to do the 2nd call

Here is my jQuery Code for the 1st and 2nd AJAX query

```
$(".showcompinfo").click(function(){
        $("#comptable").hide();
        $("#showcomptable").show();
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#comp_info").toggle();
            var companyid = id;
            var dataString = "companyid="+companyid;
            $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
                type: "POST", 
                url: "../inc/dataforms/complist.php", 
                data: dataString, 
                success: function(result){
                    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(result);
                    // here you can do your magic
                    var approved = jsonObject.customer_approved;
                    $("#showcompname").text(jsonObject.name);
                    // Get Reg Address Details - Check if any field is empty
                    var regoffice_2 = '';
                    var regoffice_3 = '';
                    var regoffice_city = '';
                    console.log(jsonObject.regoffice_city);

                    if(jsonObject.regoffice_2)
                    { 
                        regoffice_2 = ', ' + jsonObject.regoffice_2;
                    };

                    if(jsonObject.regoffice_3)
                    { 
                        regoffice_3 = ', ' + jsonObject.regoffice_3;
                    };

                    if(jsonObject.regoffice_city)
                    { 
                    var regoffice_city = ', ' + jsonObject.regoffice_city;
                    };
                    var addlne1 = jsonObject.regoffice_1;
                    var regaddress = jsonObject.regoffice_1 + regoffice_2 + regoffice_3 + regoffice_city;
                    $("#addline1").val(jsonObject.regoffice_1);
                    $("#addline2").val(jsonObject.regoffice_2);
                    $("#addline3").val(jsonObject.regoffice_3);
                    $("#addcity").val(jsonObject.regoffice_city);
                    $("#addcounty").val(jsonObject.regoffice_county);
                    $("#countryselected").val(jsonObject.regoffice_country);
                    $("#countryselected").text(jsonObject.regoffice_country);
                    $("#addpostcode").val(jsonObject.regoffice_postcode);

                    console.log(regaddress);
                    if(approved == '1')
                    {
                        $("#approvedcust").text('Yes');
                    } else {
                        $("#approvedcust").text('Customer but Not Approved');
                    };

                }
            }); 
            // 2nd Ajax 
            var companyid2 = jsonObject.company_id;
            var dataString2 = "companyid="+companyid2; 
            $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
                type: "POST", 
                url: "../inc/updatesession.php", 
                data: dataString2, 
                success: function(){    
        }
        }); 
    //
```

Here is the PHP code for complist.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['companyid'])) 
{
$companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `comp_companies` WHERE `company_id` = '$companyid'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($result){
$newdata = json_encode($result);
}
}
print_r($newdata);
```

If anyone can help even consolidate this into 1 ajax query or help me get 2 calls 
working correctly it would be much appreciated

** EDIT **
OK I now have it displaying the Company ID in the session variable however when the user clicks to view a different company info result the session company_id does not update
I have changed the complist.php to the following

```
if(!empty($_POST['companyid'])) 
{
unset($_SESSION['company_id']);
$companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `comp_companies` WHERE `company_id` = '$companyid'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($result){
$_SESSION['company_id'] = $_POST['companyid'];
$newdata = json_encode($result);
}
}
print_r($newdata);
```

My thinking behind the above was that once the ajax call is made it immediately unsets the session variable company info
then once a result is found for the selected company it resets the session var company_id with the new value, however its not updating the session variable

Screenshots showing what I mean
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a general point (not related to your issue directly), your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: "when the user clicks to view a different company info result the session company_id does not update"...if the user selected a valid company, it seems unlikely that this is the case. Also how do you know that? How have you tested it?. It's not clear. As long as the `if ($result)` block is entered then the value should be updated in the session. You need to trace your code back to see where it starts to go wrong. Verify that the ajax request sends all the right data, that the query returns correctly, that it enters the `if` block etc.

Comment: P.S. You should be using `echo $newdata` instead of `print_r($newdata)` - print_r is a debugging tool and may on occasion print extra characters which are not actually part of your variable, and which would thus cause your output to be invalid JSON.

Comment: ok just to point out the JSON being printed back to the script is all correct and working fine

Comment: My issue now is that the session var company info does not update
I have also tried setting the session variable before the if(!empty) statement based on the POST value

It does update howvever it does not reflect the change when it displays the new company data

Will try and attach a screenshot to show this

Comment: "the JSON being printed back to the script is all correct " Yes. I said it _may on occasion_ print extra characters. Don't get used to using it for all your output. `echo` is the thing to use.

Comment: We don't need a screenshot, we can take your word for it. What we need is debugging data. "It does update howvever it does not reflect the change when it displays the new company data". So you're saying the SESSION value _does_ get updated? So the problem is unrelated to the session in that case. Either way, your code above never uses the value in the session to do anything useful. All the changes to the screen seem to be made via the "success" callback in the AJAX, as far as I can see? And that uses the `result` data from the AJAX call. Maybe start looking there instead for problems.

Comment: My reason for setting the session value to the company ID is for use further down the line as a lot of tasks for this project will be done in PHP not javascript / jquery

Comment: Ok and that's fine and sensible, but it's nothing to do with your current problem. What precisely is not being updated? Are you saying it doesn't display the newly selected company details on screen? Are there any errors in your browser's console? What is the content of `result` when it comes back from the AJAX call? Is it what you expected? Was $_POST["companyid"] what you expected when the PHP ran? Trace the values of your variables as the code moves through the different stages of the process so you can narrow down the place where the problem occurs.

Comment: I just need the php session variable to reflect the current company id for the company being shown , which at present isnt the case as for some reason it doesnt display the change until you leave the current page

Comment: the result is all being displayed exactly as required without issues.
The new company details are displayed correctly on selection change however the session variable company_id does not display correctly until the screen refreshes which is not what I need

Comment: " it doesnt display the change until you leave the current page" and "the result is all being displayed exactly as required without issues." I'm sorry but these statements appear to contradict each other. Are you referring to two different things with these comments? It would help if you could make clear precisely what you mean by "the change" and "the result", so we know exactly what is and isn't working as you expected

Comment: See attached screenshots

Ignore the result which focuses on the company data being displayed , thats working fine & displaying correctly based on whichever company is selected
The issue is that the session company_id  does not get shown correctly for the selected company until the screen changes for some strange reason
in the 4th screenshot I selected the 2nd company in the list ( company ID 2 ) however when it displays the data for the 2nd company the session variable still shows the previous company id however if I refresh the page it will show the correct ID

Comment: "The issue is that the session company_id does not get shown correctly for the selected company until the screen changes for some strange reason ". It's not strange at all. Although I can't see your HTML in order to be sure, I should think that none of JavaScript your code updates that part of the screen. The PHP which sets the value based on the session is not executed. You only executed complist.php, none of your other PHP was executed. If you want that bit of the screen to change after the AJAX request, then you need to write some JS code to make that happen.

Comment: <span id="showcompname"></span><span><?php echo $_SESSION['company_id'];?></span>

Which is where the company name gets displayed

Comment: ok well that span doesn't even have an ID, so it would be very difficult to write Javascript which would locate and update it. The `echo` statement only runs when your page is initially loaded from a full refresh. It is not executed when an AJAX call runs. You just need to give that span an id and then write a line of JS to alter it, same as you do for the "showcompname" span.

Comment: Forgot to update code above my complist.php contains this
unset($_SESSION['company_id']);
if(!empty($_POST['companyid'])) 
{
$_SESSION['company_id'] = $_POST['companyid'];

so the second the ajax call hits the page it unsets the session ,
it then sets the session value once a result is found

Comment: why wouldnt echoing the php session value work ?

Comment: Yes it updates the session value on the server, but that doesn't make the `echo` statement in your page code run. The bit of PHP containing the `echo` is **not executed** when your AJAX call runs. Only the code in complist.php runs, nothing else. It just returns the JSON (which becomes the `result` variable in your JavaScript) and then stops.

Comment: What would you suggest to fix this because I'm really starting to regret using jquery at all in the project as doing it all in PHP would have been so much easier
but I'm trying to learn jquery hence i've done it this way.. close to headbutting a wall at the moment

Comment: There's nothing to _fix_ per se. The system's behaving exactly as it's supposed to, based on the code you've written. There's simply a line of code missing from your JavaScript. I've written an answer below. JS and AJAX is nice to enhance the user experience, it's a good idea to use it. You seem to have mostly got the hang of using it - you've written lots of code to update the other company details based on the response you get from the server. I'm not really sure why you've got into a muddle about just the ID field, you simply need to update that the same as all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code updates your session variable successfully. However, since you're making an AJAX call, only the code in the PHP script directly called by the AJAX ("complist.php" in this case) is executed on the server. None of the PHP code which originally used to create your page is run again - this is why you have to use JavaScript to populate the rest of your newly selected company details.

To update the ID on screen following the AJAX call, all you need to do is follow the pattern you've used to update the rest of the fields

Change your HTML so the element which contains the company ID has an ID which lets JavaScript identify it:

```
<span id="showcompname"></span><span id="showcompid"><?php echo $_SESSION['company_id'];?></span>
```

and then in the "success" callback of your AJAX code, write

```
$("#showcompid").text(jsonObject.company_id);
```

This is exactly the same concept as the other JavaScript code you've got e.g. to update the "showcompname" element.

Meanwhile, the value stored in your PHP session will be used next time you run the PHP code which updates the whole page (e.g. by refreshing the page).

Comment: Thank you .. this was really driving me nuts ..
I'm extremely new to jquery and while I love trying to learn new languages was really beginning to wish I hadnt 
Working exactly as it should now ...
Many thanks :)

Comment: @ChrisYates no problem. I think it was simply a conceptual thing you needed to get your head round about what the ajax request is actually doing (and what it isn't). More to do with the use of ajax than the use of jQuery really, IMO.

Comment: Just glad its actually doing what I wanted it to do , thanks again